# npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall mkdir npm ERR! path D:\ - npm install error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use VS Code on my DDrive for storage reasons. I have node and npm installed, however, whenever I try to "npm install *package*" I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path D:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\xpath
```

I tried installing the package on cmd with admin, as well as clearing the npm cache with force while VS Code is closed, but nothing worked.
I believe the problem is because my files on the D-Drive are read-only. However, whenever I try to untick the read-only on my files they just automatically re-tick back again.
I also tried to give full control of the drive to my user account (the only user account on my pc) but that also didn't work.